# split value and add in to spinner

Tags: android, spinner

want to add pipeline seprated value in to spinner.
I have String defined below.

> String value =
>   12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35;

how to split this value and add it in to spinner.

Comment: first split it with java's string.split() method, store it in an arraylist then create an adapter for spinner using this arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the split method to do that:

```
String values = "12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35";
//to seperate by pipeline
String[] separatedValues = values.split("|");
OR
//to seperate each character individually
String[] separatedValues = values.split("(?!^)")

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, separatedValues);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: split working. but it will give singel value. like 1 than 5 then |

Comment: I have modified the answer for you please check now. If that is what you are asking for...